# jQuery, Difference between Firefox and Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, google-chrome

For example I have this snippet of html code:

```
    .....
    <span class="no">   1</span> require <span class="s"><span class="dl">'</span><span class="k">yaml</span><span class="dl">'</span></span>
    <span class="no">   2</span> require <span class="s"><span class="dl">'</span><span class="k">set</span><span class="dl">'</span></span>
    <span class="no">   3</span>
    <span class="no">   4</span> <span class="r">module</span> <span class="cl">ActiveRecord</span> <span class="c">#:nodoc:</span>
    <span class="no">   5</span>   <span class="c"># Generic Active Record exception class.</span>
    <span class="no">   6</span>   <span class="r">class</span> <span class="cl">ActiveRecordError</span> &lt; <span class="co">StandardError</span>
    <span class="no">   7</span>   <span class="r">end</span>
    .....
```

Then I'm running this jQuery code in Firefox and Chrome browsers:

```
$('.no')[0]
```

In Chrome I've got:

```
<span class=​"no">​   1​</span>​
```

But in Firefox I've got not full element:

```
<span class="no">
```

This difference is really makes mess in my project, please explain me why and how to avoid this problem. Thanks

Comment: This seems very unlikely. I suspect that you are misinterpreting something (probably the representation of an element in the debug console for your browser). What makes you think that you are getting a start tag rather then an element? What are you trying to do with the data you get that this is causing you a problem?

Comment: They're the same thing like Quentin said; they're just displayed differently by the debug consoles.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That might be just the way the firebug or chrome debugger displays it. Have you tried doing something like

```
alert ( $('.no')[0].html() );
```